# W3C Validation Images - Very Large - Is there an Alternative?

Tags: w3c

The W3C Validation images are very large. Are there by any chance alternatives that could be used with a much reduced size as attached image compares? The XML GENERATOR is mush smaller and tidyier.[image: Image Comparison]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used these a while back:

- [image]
- [image]

But I personally prefer plain text in the footer (taken from my site):

- [image]

Comment: That is much better. Thanks Blender.

Comment: No problem. You could've just Googled these ;)

Comment: I tried Google first but I did not find what I was looking for. May not have been using the best search.